# Calculation for sidebar fixed when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using position absolute to have a sidebar stick to the viewable top of a parent div.  For example.  Parent DIV is located at X:20% and Y:20% of the entire screen.  Inside Parent Div I have a sidebar DIV positioned absolute that is set to Top:0 and Right:0.

As the parent div scrolls I increase the margin-top so that is always stays at the top of viewable area.  I have been struggling with the calculation for this and just can't seem to get the difference between pageOffset, scollTop, etc.  I have been thru w3schools and it still isn't making sense.

Here is the calculation I have so far but for some reason in IE the sidebar jumps.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

```
var s = $(".sidebar");
var pos = s.position();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    (windowpos >= 270) ? s.css("marginTop", Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() - 270) + "px") : s.css("marginTop", 0);
});
```

Comment: UPDATE: I worked out the calculation for the scroll but for some reason in IE it jitters as you scroll.  Chrome and Firefox are smooth.  Can anyone help with this issue?  Here is the Fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/yq3rcp0j/7/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly this should be a good example:

```
var s = $(".sidebar");
var pos = s.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= pos) {
            s.addClass('new-styles');
        } else {
            s.removeClass('new-styles');
        }
    });
```

the styles:

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute; // or relative
    top: 100px;
}
.new-styles {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but setting the position to fixed breaks it out of the parent div, the parent div is not at the top.  It automatically jumps to the top and all the way to the left side of the screen, which is also outside the parent div.  The best I could come with is to just use absolute and calculate the top to shift.